# How can I change the href of a Javascript created page after bundling with webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, module

I'm trying to use webpack with a project and I'm having trouble with dynamically created pages.
I have three dynamically created modules for a header, a footer ,and one other page.

Per example in header.js, I have a navbar with link such as "/src/html/about.html".

When I run the live server from the src folder I encounter no problem at all. The problem comes when I run webpack and I bundle everything into the dist folder. The paths inside the .js files to not change and my index.html can not load them up properly.

header.js looks like this but is lengthier, navbarLogo.href is the example:

```
const displayHeader = () => {
const navbar = document.createElement('div');
    navbar.classList.add('navbar');
    centeredContainer.appendChild(navbar);

const navbarLogo = document.createElement('a');
    navbarLogo.classList.add('navbar-logo');
    navbarLogo.href = "/src/index.html";
    navbar.appendChild(navbarLogo);
}

export default displayHeader;
```

Do you know how to handles these types of path problems?

Comment: add some code please!

Comment: @MadhuNair oh sorry, it's done now!